# rkhunter and wpa_supplicant

Tags: networking, wpa-supplicant, rkhunter

I suspect my laptop being hacked.
Here's one of the rkhunter log lines I do not like:

> [11:01:45] Info: Starting test name 'packet_cap_apps'
> [11:01:46]   Checking for packet capturing applications      [ Warning ]
> [11:01:46] Warning: Process '/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant' (PID 1201) is listening on the network.

Yes, I connect my latpop to WIFI. But I do not expect my device to listen to the network.
My questions are:

- is it a normal behavior?
- If not, where is the default configuration file in use by wp_supplicant?

Thanks for your answers

Dave

Comment: No it is not. rkhunter (and any of these tools) is a piece of crap: using WINDOWS rules to investigate LINUX is stupid  "process '/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant' (PID 1201) is listening on the network" That is the whole idea of wpa_supplicant. "It implements WPA key negotiation with a WPA Authenticator and EAP authentication with Authentication Server. In addition, it controls the roaming and IEEE 802.11 authentication/association of the wireless LAN driver." How to do that w/o listening the network is beyond me ...

Comment: We have no OS/product/release details; so we'd be *guessing* anyway

Comment: uname -a
Linux myhost 5.19.0-45-generic #46~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 7 15:06:04 UTC 20 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Dave - that provides kernel details, with that kernel being used by multiple OSes so you've still not said what OS/product you're using (no-one asked for what kernel you're using!).  This also isn't a forum (but a Q&A site) so answers will be to your question that still has no OS/release, not even kernel details  (*comments are just that, comments to the Original Poster or prior commenter*)

Comment: Maybe you could be more explicit then on which information you are looking for?

Comment: What OS & release are you actually using.  If it's Ubuntu, what Ubuntu product (eg. Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, Ubuntu Core 22 etc).  The Server/Desktop/Core is the product & 20.04 being the release...   FYI:  Your provided kernel says 22.04.1, where 22.04.1 used the 5.15 kernel not 5.19 so if you're using 22.04.1 you're behind on security upgrades/fixes etc!  however the 22.04.1 in the kernel isn't release details but packaging detail (which may/may-not represent the OS its used on!)